# Как в Excel написать формулу (или макрос) для проверки соблюдения нескольких условий?

Tags: условия, excel, макросы

Суть вот в чем, нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе в таблицу двух значений (длина и погрешность), программа проверяла их соответствие. 
Поясню. У нас обязательно соблюдение следующих условий:

```
погрешность max 1%, если L>= 80    
погрешность max 0.5%, если L>= 100      
погрешность max 0.25%, если L>= 120
```

Если мы вводим в таблицу длину 60 и допустимую погрешность 0.25, программа должна выдать ошибку, или где-то отобразить, что значения не соответствуют нашим условиям. 
Это должно помочь новичкам при заполнении журнала, дабы не допустить ошибок.

Comment: сделайте отдельное поле что-то типа - Наличие ошибок.
В него вбейте, допустим 

    Если(L <= 120 И погрешность<0,25);<вычисления для правильного варианта>;"Ошибка"

Короче говоря получится такая вот лесенка условий.


Comment: Bo3DuX

Так не получается. 
Суть-то я понял, но сразу два условия через функцию "И" в функцию "ЕСЛИ" добавить не получается, как скобки не расставляй, ругается ошибками.

Comment: Вот спасибо Вам, добрый человек! Так работает. 
Если Вас не затруднит, помогите усовершенствовать формулу, чтобы проверялось соответствие сразу 3-х длин. 

Если L>=80;L<=100;ПГ>=1 сюда же L>=100;L<=120;ПГ >=0.5 сюда же L>=120;ПГ>=0.25

Comment: что значит слова сюда же? при выполнении любого из этих условий должно записываться одно и то же значение?

Comment: если честно - я не вижу вариантов оптимизации.

Comment: Ребята, Ваша помощь неоценима, спасибо огромное! 
Во3DUX 
Под словами "сюда же" я имел ввиду соблюдение одновременно всех вышеперечисленных условий. Поясню, заполняем журнал, вписываем длину, затем погрешность, допустимую для этой длины. Длина может находится в 3-х диапазонах: 
80=<L<100, в этом случае Погрешность (далее ПГ) >=1
100=<L<120, в этом случае ПГ >=0,5
L>=120, в этом случае ПГ >=1

Comment: Вот как это вписать одной строкой? У меня получился рабочий вариант только с такими "косылищами":

ЕСЛИ((N29+N30+N31)=1;"ОК";"!Ошибка!")

ЕСЛИ(И(L>=80;L<100;ПГ>=1);1;0)

ЕСЛИ(И(L>=100;L<120;ПГ>=0,5);1;0)

ЕСЛИ(И(L>=120;ПГ>=0,25);1;0)

N29, N30 и N31 - адрес ячеек, в которых вбито условие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите, забыл.
В Excel префиксная форма записи, т.к. "И","Или","Не" здесь функции.

правильней будет так :

```
Если( И(L <= 120; погрешность<0,25);<вычисления для правильного варианта>;"Ошибка")
```

тестилось на Excel 2010

и лучше всего это применять только если вам надо использовать эти параметры в будущем.

Answer (score 3):

Уточните задачу. Если длина первична, то формула по Вашим условиям:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕСЛИ(A1>=120;B1<=0,0025;ЕСЛИ(A1>=100;B1<=0,005;ЕСЛИ(A1>=80;B1<=0,01)));"молодец";"А кому по пальцам?!")
```

где *A1* - длина, *B1* - погрешность.

Можно немного сократить:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СУММ((A1>={120;100;80})*(B1<={0,25;0,5;1}/100));"да";"Ошибка!")
```

*Меню Данные-Проверка_данных-Параметры-Тип_данных-Другой-Формула.*

Если выделить ячейку и по этому пути прописать часть первой формулы, при некорректном вводе запись в ячейку будет запрещена и появится сообщение о неправильном вводе данных.